# Gradle: get folder from which "gradle" was executed

Tags: gradle

I am trying to use gradle tasks as kind of "OS agnostic shell-script". I have no problems in writing the logic of the build file, but I would like to be able to run it from any folder.

My first attempt was to put a folder  with my build.gradle file on the path, and then try to execute:

```
gradle myMask
```

from a folder that doesn't contain build.gradle - but that doesn't work.

My next attempt was:

```
gradle -b /folder/containing/build.gradle myTask
```

But that worked only to some extend.  In my task I would like to find all files in CURRENT DIRECTORY. current - meaning not the one that contains build.gradle but the one from within which I am executing "gradle ....."

I have tried:

```
file(".")
```

and

```
file("$projectDir")
```

and some more, but all of them point to the folder containing build script, no the one from 
which I am executing it.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

and the winner is:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```