# Path to project on which Gradle task is executed

Tags: gradle

I have parent and child project. Parent's `build.gradle` is empty, `settings.xml` contains `include 'child'` and
in `build.gradle` of child I have a task

```
task('executionPath') << {
    println projectDir
}
```

This task is supposed to print the path to project on which the build was started.

If I invoke it **in root** by `./gradlew executionPath` I expect it to show **path of the root project**, e.g. `C:\projects\parent`.

If I invoke it **in root** by `./gradlew child:executionPath` I expect it to show **path of the child project**, e.g. `C:\projects\parent\child`.

I've tried the following:

- `projectDir` always path to child
- `new File('.')` always path to parent
- `System.getProperty("user.dir")` always path to parent

Answer [Gradle: get folder from which "gradle" was executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729293/gradle-get-folder-from-which-gradle-was-executed) is not helpful in my case. How can I achieve the above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: get folder from which "gradle" was executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729293/gradle-get-folder-from-which-gradle-was-executed)

Comment: @MichaelEaster this link doesn't answer my question, please see my edit

Answer (score 3):

It's not very straightforward solution, but you can use start parameters to find out, whether the task was called for the root project or for the current. Something like this:

```
task('executionPath') << {

    //find the argument representing current task
    String calledTaskName = null;
    for (String taskArgument : project.getGradle().startParameter.taskRequests.get(0).args) {
        if (taskArgument.equals(name) || taskArgument.endsWith(':'+name)) {
            calledTaskName = taskArgument;
        }
    }

    if (calledTaskName == null) {
        println 'Task was not called via arguments'
        return;
    }

    //check, whether task was called on root project or for subproject only
    if (calledTaskName.startsWith(project.getPath())) {
        println projectDir
    } else {
        println System.getProperty("user.dir")
    }
}
```

This task is looking within start parameters for the current task name. If it was called via start parameters, it checks, whether task name contains current project name as a prefix and according to it prints out current project path or root project path.

Unfortunately, I don't know any other solution for your case. Sure, you may need to modify it for your exact purposes.