# Upload APK to Firebase app distribution using CircleCI

Tags: android, gradle, circleci

I had a config file of CircleCI, I can checkout my repo, build the project, everything works fine, but when I try to upload my apk to firebase app distribution, I get this error :

```
> Task :app:appDistributionUploadDebug FAILED Using APK path in the outputs directory: /home/circleci/project/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk. Uploading APK to Firebase App Distribution... Getting appId from output of google services plugin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadDebug'.
> no JSON input found
```

my circleci config file looks like that:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-29



    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Store Google Services Key
          command: echo $GOOGLE_SERVICES_KEY | base64 -d > app/google-services.json

      - run:
          name: Store Google Services Account
          command: echo $GOOGLE_SERVICES_ACCOUNT | base64 -d > google-services-account.json

      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}

      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}



      - run:
          name: Build debug APK
          command: ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug

      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/
          destination: apk

      - run:
          name: Publish APK to Firebase Distribution
          command: ./gradlew assembleDebug appDistributionUploadDebug
```

in my app build gradle I have this code, this file `google-services-account.json` has some secret data :

```
  buildTypes {

        release {
            ....
        }
        debug {

            ...

        }

        getByName("debug") {
            firebaseAppDistribution {
                serviceCredentialsFile="./google-services-account.json"
                releaseNotes="First publish"
                groups="internal-tester"
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.getProperty("user.dir”)`.  You probably need to help CircleCI determine where exactly Gradle is executing from.  If the JSON file is located in the same directory as where Gradle is being executed, you can use this in your `build.gradle`:

```sh
 buildTypes {

        release {
            ....
        }
        debug {

            ...

        }

        getByName("debug") {
            firebaseAppDistribution {
                serviceCredentialsFile=System.getProperty("user.dir").replaceAll("/+$", "") + "/google-services-account.json"
                releaseNotes="First publish"
                groups="internal-tester"
            }
        }

    }
```

The `replaceAll()` call trims trailing slashes, if any.

See this question as a reference:

- [Gradle: get folder from which "gradle" was executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729293/gradle-get-folder-from-which-gradle-was-executed)

Comment: thank's, but it's not working I got the same error